# Distance between 3 stations

Tags: probability

There are $3$ stations that are distributed uniformly over $10$ units of distance and I wish to find the probability of the three of them being only at most $1$ unit of distance apart from the others. I signified $X,Y,Z \sim Uni(0,10)$ and I calculated $$P(|X-Y|<1 \cup |X-Z|<1 \cup|Y-Z|<1)$$
by drawing these relations graphically and finding the ratios of the areas. The last inequality is dependent upon the others, because if $|X-Y|<1$ and $|X-Z|<1$ then $|Y-Z|<2$. Is there an easier way to solve it? I haven't received a correct answer so I was wondering if that's even a correct way to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean volume, rather than area, since it's a region in $3$-space.  Personally, I'd find it easier to set up the integrals:

$$\frac6{1000}\int_0^9\int_x^{x+1}\int_x^z dy\,dz\,dx+\frac6{1000}\int_9^{10}\int_x^{10}\int_x^z dy\,dz\,dx$$

Here I've assumed $X\leq Y\leq Z$, and then multiplied by $6$ to take care of the other cases.

**EDIT**

In response to OP's comment I believe I've found the error in the answer sheet.  $\frac3{100}$ is the value of  $$\frac6{1000}\int_0^{10}\int_x^{x+1}\int_x^z dy\,dz\,dx$$ so I would guess that the answer was computed in a manner equivalent to this.  I doubt it was computed with the integral, since it's plain that it allows $y$ and $z$ to take values greater than $10$.  Probably some "simpler" method that obscures what's happening was used.

Comment: The correct answer seems to be $3/100$ from the answers sheet, but here it is $7/250$.  I'm trying to find a flaw in your calculation to no avail.

Comment: @Darkenin I get the same answer you did on working out the integral.

Comment: @Darkenin 30 seems incorrect. If you can visualize it, it is a parallelepiped going diagonally [starting near $(0, 0, 0)$ and ending near $(10, 10, 10)$]. The cross section (looking diagonally) is a rhombus with side $\sqrt2$ and area $\sqrt3$. The length using Pythagoras is $9 \sqrt3$. That gives volume of $27$ for the parallelepiped. Now what is left on both ends is just a fraction of unit cube, the remaining part at each end will have volume less than $1$ so it cannot add to take total sum to $30$.